# Wordpress determine which file is enqueueing script

Tags: css, wordpress

In my Wordpress site, the "pure css" (purecss.io) framework is included in my header, and I want to get rid of it.  I'm sure it was included there in  `wp_enqueue_script()`, but for the life of me I can't figure out which file or plugin included it to remove it!!

I created a new theme and deleted ALL other themes. 
I downloaded the entire `wp-content/plugins` directory and performed a search on the whole folder for the yahooapis URL, found nothing.

Anyone know what my next step might be?  I need to get rid of it because it's causing some of my new styles to be messed up, and it's included at the bottom of the list of scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: Check in your theme's functions file, usually `functions.php` otherwise just do a search for the filename within the theme folder to figure out where it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

You try the wp_dequeue_script() function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

```
function purecss_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'pure-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'purecss_dequeue_script', 100 );
```